# Rails loads my @items n*n times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I am creating a rails web app which basically just aggregates a list of users posts and allows them to vote and comment.

I was implementing endless scrolling by following the Railscast 114 - Endless Scrolling
post, although I have run into an issue that I am unsure if it is related to the endless scrolling, or just happened at the same time.

I am using the will_paginate gem. When the page is loaded it loads "n" number of posts  the will_paginate call, but then those posts are displayed n times over.

For example:

```
@item.order(params[:sort]).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)
```

Would result in the following being displayed

```
item1
item2
item3
item1
item2
item3
item1
item2
item3
```

I have the following in my index action

```
@items = Item.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
```

this is my _item partial

```
<% @items.each do |t| %>
<div id="Post1" class="shadow">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        t.stuff....
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And this is the render call in my index

```
<div id='items'>
  <%= render @items %>
</div>
```

It feels like its something simple, but I just cannot find it. Any suggestions on where to look would be much appreciated

Comment: Try changing `render @items` to `render 'item'`.

Comment: This worked, I had it as `item` originally but that was not working so I switched to `@items` Still not sure how `@items` was duplicating it though. Thanks

Comment: I've had similar issue many months ago ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: change

```
<div id='items'>
  <%= render @items %>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id='items'>
  <%= render 'item' %>
</div>
```

Former version renders `item` partial for each object in `@items` collection (where you're iterating again over each element), that's why you get n*n items.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

`Item.paginate...` not `Item.order`... , see the will paginate guide [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use)